# How to solve Quadratic Program in vector form?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

[image: the question detail]

I've gotten Q matrix and Y vector, Q matrix is a 7x7 matrix, but the "NMinimize" in wolfram seem can only solve the real number not vector, how to solve it in vector form? (alpha 7x1 vector, Y 7x1 vector)

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.

Comment: Check refguide for `FindMinimum`, examples in `Scope` section near bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, `FindMinimum` and `NMinimize` can't work directly with vectors. So the standard way to do this is to create N separate (scalar) variables, and optimize those:

```
xs = Array[x, 7];
```

The vector `xs` now contains 7 separate variables `x[1]`..`x[7]`. (Make sure you haven't used the symbol `x` elsewhere!) You can optimize those:

```
q = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {7, 7}];
y = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 7];
{minValue, solution} = 
     FindMinimum[{xs.q.xs/2 - Total[xs], Thread[xs >= 0], y.xs == 0}, xs]
```

will return something like:

> {-88.2984, {x[1] -> 32.6369, x[2] -> 26.9988, x[3] -> 3.22452*10^-11, 
>     x[4] -> 52.524, x[5] -> 15.2339, x[6] -> 8.40908, x[7] -> 40.794}}

And `xs /. solution` gives the optimized vector

Comment: nice answer! I'm a beginner of mathemathica. lol